# Cordova emulator not starting

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am trying to use the Android emulator to install an app on it.

Unfortunately the emulator is never starting up. I use the following
command in my cordova project:

```
cordova emulate android
```

The last output I get from console is:

```
Waiting for emulator...
```

But the emulator does never start (I waited 45 minutes now).

The path variables are all correctly set and I can start the
emulator using Eclipse or Android studio but not using the 
command from cordova.

Any hints?

Comment: What about using Android x86 on Virtualbox instead? It's also much faster than the emulator, because it doesn't have to do the arm-x86 translation.

Comment: can you open the emulator first? open the emulator (using eclipse may be) and provide the command after that. I faced this issue once. I just opened it before giving the command. and all worked well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can start the emulator through android studio, then as a work around start the emulator outside and run the command

```
cordova run android
```

It will deploy your app in the already running emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Check emulator path settings
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html
If not able to execute then do  :
 use the alternate shell interface:

```
$ /path/to/project/cordova/run --emulator
```

Instead of relying on whichever emulator is currently enabled within the SDK, you can refer to each by the names you supply:

```
$ /path/to/project/cordova/run --target=NAME
```

Check the documentation above and see whether your PC supports virtualization or not.

Comment: Everything is set up correctly and virtualization is supported on my pc. i guess i will just use my device to test everything instead of using the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue, I resolved it by:

Open Android device manager, click on window -> Android Virtual Device Manager

There you will see listing of all the Android Virtual Devices, if you see any device with repairable icon on it, just click on repair and then try. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Though cordova started the emulator, the command line kept on saying 'Waiting for emulator...' forever.

The trick is, before running the command:

cordova run android
make sure you navigate into the android platform folder. That is, don't run the command from within the

```
/project folder
```

but instead from within

```
/project/platforms/android folder
```

That will launch your application in the Android emulator

Comment: What do I have to install for me to emulate on android?